# Multi-line right-aligned text with left-border close to text

Tags: html, css, right-align

Im trying to have a right-aligned text with a border that starts where the text starts, on the left.

Problems :

1. If I use a span, the border does not encapsulate multiple lines (border-top/bottom get messed up).
2. If I use a span with inline-block, it kind of becomes similar to a div, the border on the left starts on the left side and not where the text starts.
3. If I use a paragraph, it's just like a div as well.
4. If I use a div, border is on the left as well.

Basically, what I would like is (where | is the left border):

```
    | Text
```

But I only manage to get :

```
|     Text
```

Comment: How about showing us some markup?  Maybe create a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `inline-block` inside a `block` might work. Or even simpler.

```html
<div style="text-align: right">
  <div style="text-align: right; display:inline-block; border-left: 1px solid red;">
    some text<br> that spans two lines<br>
  </div>
</div>
```